# .gsub(/\..../, "").gsub(/\(/, "").gsub(/\)/,"").gsub(/\localhost/, "") <= That's a handful

Tags: ruby, regex, bash

I'm writing a program that will pull the information from a `who` command and format the output.

Normal `who` command:

```
user ip date (ip)
user ip date (ip)
user ip date (ip)
user ip date (ip)
user ip date (ip)
user ip date (ip)
user ip date (ip)
user ip date (ip)
user ip date (ip)
user ip date (ip)
```

My new take on `who` command:

```
user
user
user
user
user
user
user
user
user
user
user
```

In order to do this, I had to completely remove the digits with `gsub` and some other stuff, and the entire line looks like this:

```
`who`.gsub!(/\d+/, "").gsub!(/\..../, "").gsub!(/\(/, "").gsub(/\Dec/, "").gsub(/\:/, "").gsub(/\pts/, "").gsub(/\//, "").gsub(/\./, "").gsub(/\)/, "").gsub(/\localhost/, "").gsub(/\Nov/, "").squeeze(" ").strip
```

Is there a better way to write this regex without all these `gsub`'s?

**EDIT:**

Updated `who` output from accepted answer:  `` puts `who`.gsub(/[ \t].*/,"") ``

Output now looks like this:

```
John
Jim
Jake
Steve
Josh
Eric
etc..
```

Comment: Just split the string and echo the first field ?

Comment: Or perhaps use quick mode if your version of who has it.   who -q  ?

Comment: Well apparently there was a super easy way to do this and I'm an idiot.

Comment: I love this title lol, nicely done.

Comment: When asking, please use a more definitive example of your input. You say you're removing digits but your sample shows none. While we can divine what you want, it'd be better that people don't have to guess because that adds variability to the question and answers. It's easy to substitute 192.168... or 127.0... range IPs if those are sensitive values you don't want to reveal, or extract examples from the documentation since those are already sanitized and out there. It helps us help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three approaches.. First, try the `users` command. :)

Second:

```
 who | sed -e 's/[ \t].*//g'
```

Third:

```
 puts `who`.gsub(/[ \t].*/,"")
```

All three are much shorter and much simpler.

Comment: ``puts `who`.gsub(/[ \t].*/,"")`` Lol, I need to get better at `regex`'s. Thanks man

Comment: Any time. ;)  I like Ryan's solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

How about with no regular expressions at all?

```
users = `who`.each_line.map do |line|
    line.split.first
end
```

Or, if this is the entire utility, it could just be:

```
who | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

@DavidHoelzer is right, though; use `users`. =)

Comment: `users` doesn't output the information in the way I need it outputted, `who` does

Comment: I'd use the `who` pipe through `awk`. It should be blazing fast.

Comment: Wouldn't piping it to `cut` be faster?

Comment: It probably would. `awk` is not the fastest tool, it's just more flexible.

Comment: @Jordan: I had originally written it using `cut`, but thought it was too specific (compare `who | cut -d ' ' -f 2` to `who | awk '{ print $2 }'`).

Answer (score 3):

One of the things I see often is people wanting to extract information by deleting everything that doesn't belong, instead of simply taking what they do want. It's faster to take what you want than to remove what you don't, especially when dealing with lots of text, and it results in code that's easier to follow usually.

If I want to take the first word in a line, I want everything up to the first white-space. It's easy to grab just that:

```
who_out = <<EOT
user1 tty7        2012-08-07 05:33 (:0)
user2 192.168.0.1 2012-08-07 06:47 (:0.0)
user3 127.0.0.1   2012-08-07 07:58 (:0.0)
EOT

who_out.lines.map{ |l| l[/^\S+/] }     # => ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
who_out.lines.map{ |l| l[/\A\S+/] }    # => ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
who_out.scan(/^\S+/)                   # => ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
who_out.scan(/^\w+/)                   # => ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
who_out.lines.map{ |l| l.split.first } # => ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
```

The first two look for the start of the lines (`^` and `\A`) and return everything that is not white-space (`\S+`) up to the first white-space.

`scan` looks for line-beginnings (`^`) and finds the text up to the same first white-spaces in each line. `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` which is approximately what we'd want for user names since they usually are upper and lower-case characters plus digits and `_`.

The last one should be easily understood.

Comment: This is smart, to bad he already accepted one.. I have a question though, most `who` commands first output is `root` so would there be a way to exclude the first user..?

Comment: Is that a possibility?

Comment: @TheTinMan What are you pulling the `who_out` from? Just a normal who command?

Comment: It was a modified `who` output just to show the typical output.

Comment: @Ekult3k, of course there's a way to ignore the first line. It's also very easily done and a little research will reveal many different ways to do so.