# Pulling information from a who command on all servers

Tags: ruby, bash, ssh, server

I'm creating a program that pulls information from a `who` command, see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457653/gsub-gsub-gsub-gsub-localhost-thats) to see the format of the who command.

Now what I want to do is `ssh` to different servers and run the `who` command. Problem being I have no idea how to `ssh` in Ruby. I'm aware of `require 'net/ssh/gateway'` would somebody mind giving me an example of how I can `ssh` in Ruby and and perform a `who` command (like the linked question) on multiple servers?

For example:

```
def user
  cmd = `who`.gsub(/[ \t].*/,"")
  puts cmd
  #<= Do some fancy stuff that will ssh to the servers and run cmd
end
```

---

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Can you be more specific..?

Comment: @Ekult3k I edited the question, hope that makes thing a little bit more clear.

Comment: Please search more. This is covered well, both in the Net::SSH documentation, here on Stack Overflow, and elsewhere on the internet. There are also packages available that build upon Net::SSH. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @theTinMan I've done my research, but everything has conflicting information.. Some say that there is no `users` in the new version of `net/ssh` some say there is.. etc..

Comment: Then show where you've searched and why it's confusing. The more detail you give the faster and better your responses will be. As is you're asking for something that's already covered and we can't tell why those didn't work. I think the best source is the [actual documentation](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/) for the code, so I'd ignore anything that contradicts what the authors say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that doing something like this:

```
 26 print "Enter password: "
 27 system "stty -echo" #<= Removes echo from typing, you won't see your keystrokes
 28 @password = gets.chomp
 29 system "stty echo"
 30 
 31 def logged_in
 32   cmd = `who`.gsub(/[ \t].*/,"")
 33   check = Net::SSH.start(@host, @username, :password => @password)
 34   check.exec!(cmd)
 35 end
 36 
 37 @host = %w(servers).each do
 38   logged_in
 39 end
 40
 41 @username = Etc.getlogin
```

Will do what I want to accomplish.